# When in Debug mode in Java, is there anything like a Console where I can type commands?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible in Eclipse to have a Console, where when in Debug mode I can try out things? Like in python, where I can type at any moment for example 1+1 or myVariable.toString(), etc? C# has a similar concept with the F# shell.

I'd like to inspect my variables at run-time and try out some methods, having that kind of console would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: The "Variables" tab should allow you to inspect the same variables

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to run commands, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eclipse has the Display view, where you can enter (almost) arbitrary Java expressions and have them evaluated whenever you are in a breakpoint.

To have any expression evaluated select it (either in the Display view itself, or any open Java source file) and push one of the "inspect", "display" or "evaluate" buttons.

- "inspect" executes the expression and shows the resulting value in a pop-up inspection view (similar to the Variables view).
- "display" executes the expression and prints the resulting value into the Display view
- "evaluate" executes the expression and does nothing else

There some very good help on [debugging in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-running_and_debugging.htm), specifically about [inspecting variables](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-inspecting.htm) and [evaluating expressons](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-evaluating_expressions.htm).

If you want to test the behavior of some Java code while you're *not* debugging, then you might want to look into the [Scrapbook feature](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cscrapbook.htm).

Comment: I've tried to write 1+1; or this.toString(); and nothing seems to happen. How does it work?

Comment: @devoured: are you sure that you're currently debugging an application *and* are in a breakpoint? That's necessary because the execution needs some context (for example to know what `this` is).

Comment: Yes, I am. The expressions view seems to work, but when I try to type things in the Display view it seems to do nothing.

Comment: @devoured: and have you **selected** the expression you want to execute?

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. I had to select it. But isn't there a way that allows me to just write things and press ENTER to execute them? Having to write them and then having to select them and click execute from the context menu seems odd.

Comment: Then you're probably looking for a REPL. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397488/is-there-something-like-pythons-interactive-repl-mode-but-for-java

Comment: I couldn't find the Display view in v4.12.0, but there's a view called "Debug Shell" which seems the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Eclipse scrapbook - little known but very cool

File -> New -> Java -> Java Run/Debug -> Scrapbook

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse also has an old plug-in that seems to do exactly what you're looking for called Dr. Java.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; Yes.

In Java 9 there was a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) added which allows exactly like you were doing in Python.

In Eclipse you can add [QuickShell](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quickshell) to use JShell inside the Eclipse IDE. The [TM Terminal](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal) Eclipse plugin will also need to be installed.

Incidentally, in IntelliJ it's builtin via Tools | JShell Console.