# Java REPL shell

Tags: java, read-eval-print-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there something like python's interactive REPL mode, but for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397488/is-there-something-like-pythons-interactive-repl-mode-but-for-java)

I'm looking for a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) shell that I can use to test out snippets of Java code. Either a desktop app, or a web app (like the [Groovy web console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/)). Ideally, commonly used Java packages like:

```
java.io.*
java.util.*
```

should be automatically imported, so that I can copy and paste code from a class without having to add a bunch of imports. Does such a thing exist?