# Java Command Line?

Tags: java, command-line, interpreter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java REPL shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636044/java-repl-shell)

Hey,

Is there any way to execute Java code (as you type) on a command line?

For instance, something like this

```
(command line)
java

import ARDrone;
ARDrone drone = new ARDrone(null, null, null);

drone.takeoff();
```

(so that you can enter lines of code in the command line)

Comment: See [Java REPL shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636044/java-repl-shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy can do that. It's possible with java syntax and groovy syntax.

You can try at [Groovy web console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/). You have also [groovy console](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Console) and [groovy shell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29).

Google tells me that [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/intro.html) appears to be one, although I don't know Java and have never heard of BeanShell.

Comment: by the way, good answer. thanks. ill mark it as done when it allows me too.

Comment: @Christian: I meant have never heard of BeanShell :p unfortunately I have heard of Java.