# Command prompt that knows Java?

Tags: java, command-prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java REPL shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636044/java-repl-shell)

Is there a project that makes a command prompt that can execute Java statements? Why not? I'm looking for something like the builtin shell of Python but for Java.

I see there is http://www.beanshell.org/ but that project does not seem very active. But it appears to be what I'm looking for. Are there any other projects like this?

I want to be able to do something like this

`$ import org.foobar.Bletch`

`$ new Bletch();`

or similar. Has anyone done this?

Comment: Without any offense, could you tell what you do you find in a java shell?

Comment: How about [jython](http://www.jython.org/)? While this is actually a python shell built on top of java, you would be able to access all java features with it. So practically it's a java shell with python syntax and additional python features...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always use a Clojure REPL - I do this for dynamically playing with Java objects at runtime.

```
(import 'my.package.SomeClass)

(def a (new SomeClass))

(.methodName a arg1 arg2)
```

Works pretty well as long as you know the Clojure syntax.

Comment: Or a Scala REPL, which has syntax that's closer to Java than Clojure.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Groovy Shell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell) - this is not exactly Java, but very close.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.beanshell.org/

It is more than 12 years old and is used in a number of IDE's debuggers.