# Is there some sort of Java REPL/shell that I can use to quickly test class files?

Tags: java, testing, read-eval-print-loop

I need a Java REPL/shell to quickly test some class files. Since they are mostly throwaway code, I don't want to have to bother writing full-blown unit tests. And writing a Main class is also too much extra work for some quick testing.

Comment: If you don't mind learning a little Scala, the Scala REPL works well. Or maybe Jython (if you dont mind learning a littly Python)

Comment: @GyroGearless I do know Python, but I know nothing about Jython and how it interacts with Java classes.

Comment: [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) has a REPL, they call it "codepad".

Comment: @GyroGearless I tried Jython and intuitively figured out how to work it without reading any documentation. Thanks for the suggestion, you should post it as an answer!

Comment: what's about http://www.javarepl.com ?

Comment: @MathiasBegert that doesn't allow me to test my own classes. I'm not trying to experiment with Java for the first time or anything like that.

Comment: This [thread][1] answers this better. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397488/is-there-something-like-pythons-interactive-repl-mode-but-for-java/15962251#15962251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one else answered, I'll answer myself. I used Gyro Gearless's idea from the comments above. I installed Jython and it worked very well as a REPL to test out my Java classes.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled here.

As mentioned in Mathias Begert's comment, there is an on-line Java REPL at http://www.javarepl.com/console.html and the sources are available from GitHub https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl