# BeanShell command line interpreter features

Tags: java, beanshell

I'm trying to test BeanShell's command line interpreter in how it processes basic Java commands and syntax on my machine, and see if I can customise its behavior in any way.  I've installed version 2.0b4 on my machine running OS X 10.10.1 (the JAR file is in `/Library/Java/Extensions` as per the instructions).

It's the closest thing to what I've been looking for, an interactive Java interpreter, but it doesn't have some standard features which a good interpreter should have.

1. I'd like to be able to use the Up arrow key to reuse a previous command, but at the moment it doesn't recognise it, it just shows a control sequence.  Is there a way to customise this for BeanShell?
2. Is there a way to get BeanShell to print out the value of a variable if I've created it beforehand, just by naming it, like

   String s = new String( "Hello World!" );
   s; 
   Hello World!.

This is possible in Python for example.

3. According to the documentation on importing Java classes `which(<java class>);` should return the classpath location of the specified Java class.  But `which( java.lang.String );` does not work for me, I get a `NullPointerException`:

   bsh % which(java.lang.String);
   Start ClassPath Mapping
   Mapping: Directory /Users/srm
   // Error: // Uncaught Exception: Method Invocation cp.getClassSource : at Line: 42 : in file: /bsh/commands/which.bsh : cp .getClassSource ( className )

   Called from method: which : at Line: 8 : in file:  : which ( java .lang .String ) 
   Target exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

   java.lang.NullPointerException

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that as seen in question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549307/current-state-of-beanshell, BeanShell itself is not currently actively maintained.  Still I add it to every Java project I touch since it is hugely useful for development/debugging.

Comment: I should have guessed from the 90s style web page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run beanshell with jline.

Download jline jar from http://jline.sourceforge.net/index.html and then you can do:

```
java -cp jline-1.0.jar:bsh-2.0b4.jar jline.ConsoleRunner bsh.Interpreter
```

Line editing capability will be provided by jline.  I found this hint [here](https://code.google.com/p/beanshell2/issues/detail?id=52).

There are issues running with [jline2](https://github.com/jline/jline2).  First, you'll get:

```
 $ java -cp jline-2.12.jar:bsh-2.0b4.jar jline.ConsoleRunner bsh.Interpreter
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline/ConsoleRunner
```

Due to [this](https://github.com/jline/jline2/issues/21) issue which is fixed. But then, use the new class and you still get:

```
$ java -cp jline-2.12.jar:bsh-2.0b4.jar jline.console.internal.ConsoleRunner bsh.Interpreter
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

due to [this](https://github.com/jline/jline2/issues/157) issue which is not fixed yet.

2. Use show() command which will trigger showing of value.

> ```
> bsh % show();
> bsh % String s = new String("Hello World");
> bsh % s;
> <Hello World>
> bsh %
> ```

It is mentioned in the **[Useful BeanShell Commands](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html#Useful_BeanShell_Commands)** section of the documentation.

3. Doesn't work for me either

It doesn't fail in my case, but it didn't find it either.

> ```
> bsh % which(java.lang.String);
> Start ClassPath Mapping
> Mapping: Archive: file:/Users/me/beanshell/jline-1.0.jar
> Mapping: Archive: file:/Users/me/beanshell/bsh-2.0b4.jar
> Mapping: Archive: file:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
> End ClassPath Mapping
> null
> bsh %
> ```

Comment: I tried using jline2 and discovered that there are issues and doesn't work so better stick with jline1 for now.   I added details in the answer.

Comment: If jline1 is stable then I'll go with that.  Thanks again.