# Issues when using Groovysh as Java REPL

Tags: java, groovy

As this post ([Is there something like python's interactive REPL mode, but for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397488/is-there-something-like-pythons-interactive-repl-mode-but-for-java)) shows, we can use `groovysh` for Java REPL.

I have this code that compiles well with `javac`.

```
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
    shell.evaluate("println \"My name is ${name}\"");
```

However, when I tried to run this command in the `groovysh`, I got error. I had to make `\${name}` to bypass the error.

Why is this? What other possible (corner) cases that Java and Groovy code be different?

Comment: http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quoted string literals in Groovy are *GStrings*, which interpret `${...}` expressions and substitute their results into the string.  Given the Groovy code

```
shell.evaluate("println \"My name is ${name}\"")
```

Groovy will try and resolve the `name` variable in the current context, and throw an exception when it fails to find a suitable definition.

If you want to pass the `${...}` through literally (so it is interpreted by the `GroovyShell` rather than by the current Groovy context) then you either need to escape the dollar sign or use one of the other Groovy string delimiters that are not subject to `${...}` interpolation (single quotes, triple-single-quotes, or slashes):

```python
shell.evaluate('println "My name is ${name}"')
shell.evaluate('''println "My dog's name is ${dogName}"''')
```

In a single quoted string you also don't need to backslash the double quote characters.