# PowerShell-like environment for Java

Tags: java, read-eval-print-loop

I'm found a number of libraries that enable Java to call PowerShell scripts (e.g. [jPowerShell](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell).

I'm also found a simple, Java REPL environment: [Java REPL](http://www.javarepl.com/console.html).

Is there a Java REPL, however, that offers a robust pipeline metaphor, similar to PowerShell?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397488/is-there-something-like-pythons-interactive-repl-mode-but-for-java

Comment: There will be the JShell with JDK9, you can get it in early version.