# Groovy: is there a command line REPL?

Tags: groovy, read-eval-print-loop

I'm not talking about a GUI or a web app.

I'm talking about a REPL. e.g. in Python I would simply run `python` to get a REPL.

`groovy` just outputs some help text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there something like python's interactive REPL mode, but for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397488/is-there-something-like-pythons-interactive-repl-mode-but-for-java)

Answer (score 7):

Yes it's called `groovysh`

Documentation can [be found here](http://groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html)